# count exact range

Tags: excel, count, excel-2007, rows

Is there a formula or method of keeping an exact amount of rows (i.e. 100 rows always) and counting inside said rows - regardless of inserts or deletes? I've tried absolute references, but the inserts and deletes affect it.

The only method that I have now is to rewrite the formulas after all the inserts and deletes have been completed.

```
Sub ExactRowsCount()
'
' ExactRowsCount Macro
'
Range("H1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTA(R[4]C:R[104]C)"
Range("H2").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean to always have the `COUNTA` function count in the same number of rows regardless of whether rows/cells were inserted or deleted?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `OFFSET`:

```
=COUNTA(OFFSET(A1,4,0,100,1))
```

Where `A1` is the cell where you want the count to end up.  This formula may be particularly convenient if you want the column height to depend on another cell; for example, if you want to keep the column height in cell A2 instead of using a constant number 100, you could do:

```
=COUNTA(OFFSET(H1, 4, 0, A2, 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

This will return the count of non-blank cells in A2 to A101 regardless of inserts and deletes:

```
=COUNTA(INDIRECT("A2:A101"))
```

Comment: Simple answer, but I went with ikh's answer because it is more customizable. Thanks!